# Installing an npm module globally...and then node not being able to find it

Tags: node.js, npm

I install this module called zmq with `npm install -g zmq`
Say I am in a new directory and I create a simple node.js file:

//test.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
console.log(zmq);
```

...if I run this, it will not be able to find the `zmq` package, even though I installed it globally. In order for the script to work, I have to run `npm install zmq` without the -g flag, which creates a node_modules folder in the same directory. I don't want that node_modules folder there.

I am failing to see the purpose of the -g flag, since none of my node programs seem to run without a node_modules folder.

I am on a Mac, but I have had the same problem on Windows and Linux.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From npm's [website](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders):

> - Local install (default): puts stuff in ./node_modules of the current package root.
> - Global install (with -g): puts stuff in /usr/local or wherever node is installed.
> - Install it locally if you're going to require() it.
> - Install it globally if you're going to run it on the command line.

It's built this way so that each project can maintain separate dependencies and you don't have any issues trying to figure out which version goes with which project at a global level.

I'm not sure there's a way to do what you want it to do, and I don't think it would be recommended, even if there was.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what I was envisioning ever since my early days of messing with node, was that when you installed something with the -g flag the module would sit in a known shared directory. that way when you ran straight npm install X I thought it would first go to that local shared directory and then if it wasn't there look to the web for the module. the global flag is a misnomer I think.

Comment: It's possible you might be looking for a local npm registry, with a fall back to a hosted one.  While I don't have any personal experience with it, check out [Sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia).